# Azure Maps Not Rendering GeoJson Uploaded to Data Service

Tags: azure-maps

Via following this tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-render-custom-data#render-a-circle-and-pushpins-with-custom-labels, I attempted to upload my own GeoJson data for rendering in an Azure Static map.
I've confirmed that the geojson was successfully uploaded.

When I try to render it on the map, the line doesn't show. The URL I'm expecting to see the map rendered at, [https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=[key]&api-version=1.0&zoom=12&center=-61.60976,10.71847&pins=default|la15+50|al0.66|lc003C62|co002D62||udid-01c5c14c-c9d3-f98b-1007-82f0b6d06304](https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=%5Bkey%5D&api-version=1.0&zoom=12&center=-61.60976,10.71847&pins=default%7Cla15+50%7Cal0.66%7Clc003C62%7Cco002D62%7C%7Cudid-01c5c14c-c9d3-f98b-1007-82f0b6d06304)

Which produces this image:
[image]

Whereas, I expect to see this:
[image]

This is the content of that document:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates":[[-61.60976,10.71847],[-61.60995,10.71905],[-61.61013,10.71982],[-61.61018,10.72022],[-61.61068,10.72196],[-61.61089,10.72289],[-61.61112,10.72351],[-61.61129,10.72458],[-61.61144,10.72509],[-61.61191,10.72585],[-61.61218,10.72623],[-61.61242,10.7265],[-61.61288,10.72713],[-61.61326,10.72775],[-61.61346,10.72801],[-61.61365,10.72817],[-61.6138,10.72848],[-61.61397,10.72866],[-61.6144,10.72932],[-61.61494,10.73004],[-61.61531,10.73047],[-61.61553,10.73051],[-61.61568,10.73049],[-61.61613,10.73033],[-61.61649,10.73016],[-61.61663,10.73004],[-61.617,10.72984],[-61.61735,10.72966],[-61.61818,10.72903],[-61.61878,10.72867],[-61.61928,10.72827],[-61.62065,10.72742],[-61.62105,10.72724],[-61.6211,10.72727],[-61.62132,10.72768],[-61.62141,10.72777],[-61.62177,10.72776],[-61.62188,10.72785],[-61.62197,10.72829],[-61.62196,10.72859],[-61.62191,10.72872],[-61.62206,10.72913],[-61.62206,10.72946],[-61.6221,10.72957],[-61.62216,10.72965],[-61.62238,10.72978],[-61.62277,10.73017],[-61.62296,10.73055],[-61.62311,10.7307],[-61.62332,10.73146],[-61.62326,10.73188],[-61.62333,10.73225],[-61.62352,10.73235],[-61.62361,10.73246],[-61.62399,10.73267],[-61.62422,10.73295],[-61.62439,10.73285],[-61.62463,10.73278],[-61.62473,10.7328],[-61.62479,10.73291],[-61.62497,10.73303],[-61.62518,10.73301],[-61.62534,10.73289],[-61.62549,10.73283],[-61.62547,10.7327],[-61.62558,10.73263],[-61.62561,10.73256],[-61.62583,10.73239],[-61.62599,10.73235],[-61.62605,10.73219],[-61.62612,10.73212],[-61.62617,10.73213],[-61.62643,10.73196],[-61.62657,10.73194],[-61.62689,10.73191],[-61.627,10.73196],[-61.62718,10.73193],[-61.62735,10.73198],[-61.62738,10.73204],[-61.62791,10.73207],[-61.62819,10.73227],[-61.62831,10.73225],[-61.62869,10.73206],[-61.6289,10.7319],[-61.62899,10.73189],[-61.62907,10.73195],[-61.62912,10.73194],[-61.62958,10.73153],[-61.62959,10.73149],[-61.62979,10.73138],[-61.62988,10.73124],[-61.63001,10.73117],[-61.63003,10.73109],[-61.63016,10.73099],[-61.63025,10.73096],[-61.6304,10.73074],[-61.63044,10.73053],[-61.63043,10.73029],[-61.63046,10.73015],[-61.63051,10.73013],[-61.63048,10.7297],[-61.63043,10.72955],[-61.63035,10.72936],[-61.63039,10.729],[-61.63048,10.72898],[-61.63073,10.72872],[-61.63092,10.72864],[-61.63102,10.72849],[-61.63105,10.72825],[-61.63117,10.72798],[-61.63124,10.72795],[-61.63128,10.72805],[-61.63143,10.72796],[-61.63161,10.72793],[-61.63176,10.72781],[-61.63185,10.72754],[-61.6322,10.7271],[-61.63223,10.72701],[-61.63215,10.72666],[-61.63219,10.72626],[-61.6323,10.72591],[-61.63232,10.72566],[-61.63228,10.72549],[-61.63242,10.72536],[-61.63246,10.72515],[-61.63259,10.725],[-61.63266,10.72497],[-61.63284,10.72497],[-61.63293,10.725],[-61.63314,10.72499],[-61.63343,10.72475],[-61.63388,10.72462],[-61.63415,10.72445],[-61.6342,10.72439],[-61.63473,10.7242],[-61.63508,10.72386],[-61.63515,10.72366],[-61.63547,10.72346],[-61.63571,10.72312],[-61.63571,10.72305],[-61.6358,10.72292],[-61.63587,10.7229],[-61.63587,10.72286],[-61.63581,10.72287],[-61.63577,10.7228],[-61.6357,10.72279],[-61.63567,10.7226],[-61.63561,10.72254],[-61.63549,10.72247],[-61.63539,10.72251],[-61.63543,10.72241],[-61.63544,10.72229],[-61.63538,10.72217],[-61.63544,10.72191],[-61.63551,10.72192],[-61.63562,10.722],[-61.63558,10.72201],[-61.63569,10.72195],[-61.63585,10.72178],[-61.63589,10.72163],[-61.63601,10.72155],[-61.63607,10.72142],[-61.6361,10.72142],[-61.63603,10.72137],[-61.63598,10.72108],[-61.63607,10.72099],[-61.63591,10.72093],[-61.63553,10.72045],[-61.63541,10.72037],[-61.63522,10.72033],[-61.63496,10.72011],[-61.6349,10.72005],[-61.63484,10.71985],[-61.6347,10.7197],[-61.63443,10.71948],[-61.63431,10.71925],[-61.63428,10.71907],[-61.63402,10.71862],[-61.63407,10.71848],[-61.63403,10.71837],[-61.63411,10.71779],[-61.63419,10.71753],[-61.63412,10.71738],[-61.63412,10.71724],[-61.63405,10.71712],[-61.63403,10.71696],[-61.63378,10.71674],[-61.63372,10.71664],[-61.63363,10.7166],[-61.63347,10.71641],[-61.63328,10.71628],[-61.63321,10.71618],[-61.63305,10.71607],[-61.63303,10.716],[-61.6329,10.71592],[-61.63287,10.71586],[-61.63282,10.71587],[-61.63267,10.71579],[-61.63267,10.71572],[-61.63242,10.71552],[-61.6321,10.71518],[-61.63172,10.71463],[-61.63166,10.7147],[-61.63161,10.71468],[-61.63159,10.71466],[-61.63168,10.71469],[-61.63171,10.71458],[-61.63162,10.71445],[-61.63146,10.71405],[-61.63132,10.71396],[-61.6312,10.71396],[-61.63099,10.71389],[-61.63085,10.71393],[-61.63071,10.71385],[-61.63059,10.71387],[-61.63057,10.71385],[-61.63,10.71403],[-61.62979,10.71413],[-61.62929,10.71424],[-61.62914,10.71436],[-61.62904,10.71463],[-61.62883,10.71486],[-61.62817,10.71489],[-61.62789,10.71476],[-61.62756,10.71452],[-61.6274,10.71436],[-61.62704,10.71419],[-61.62688,10.71399],[-61.62653,10.7138],[-61.62607,10.7135],[-61.62595,10.7135],[-61.62588,10.71344],[-61.62553,10.71329],[-61.62546,10.71331],[-61.62535,10.71327],[-61.62528,10.71331],[-61.62514,10.71331],[-61.62479,10.71318],[-61.62463,10.71317],[-61.62447,10.71322],[-61.62442,10.7132],[-61.62423,10.71326],[-61.62405,10.7134],[-61.62407,10.71342],[-61.62408,10.71362],[-61.62389,10.71369],[-61.62404,10.71375],[-61.62386,10.71392],[-61.62396,10.71392],[-61.62408,10.71398],[-61.62414,10.71404],[-61.62413,10.7141],[-61.6239,10.71442],[-61.62383,10.71446],[-61.62389,10.71441],[-61.62389,10.71445],[-61.62375,10.71454],[-61.62383,10.71453],[-61.62379,10.71453],[-61.62381,10.71458],[-61.62374,10.71462],[-61.62379,10.71468],[-61.62372,10.71474],[-61.62354,10.71476],[-61.62347,10.7148],[-61.62341,10.71491],[-61.62342,10.71508],[-61.62336,10.71514],[-61.62338,10.71517],[-61.62329,10.71532],[-61.62333,10.71538],[-61.62311,10.71545],[-61.6232,10.71549],[-61.62314,10.7156],[-61.62312,10.71583],[-61.62306,10.71588],[-61.6231,10.716],[-61.62307,10.71601],[-61.62308,10.71607],[-61.62304,10.71612],[-61.62293,10.71617],[-61.62291,10.71612],[-61.62285,10.71628],[-61.62264,10.71642],[-61.62266,10.71647],[-61.6226,10.71665],[-61.62265,10.71682],[-61.62251,10.71723],[-61.62244,10.71771],[-61.6223,10.71796],[-61.6223,10.71814],[-61.62217,10.71837],[-61.62218,10.71848],[-61.6221,10.71868],[-61.62196,10.71883],[-61.62184,10.71888],[-61.6216,10.71882],[-61.62149,10.7186],[-61.62143,10.71833],[-61.62135,10.7183],[-61.62125,10.71817],[-61.62125,10.71805],[-61.6212,10.71808],[-61.62108,10.71797],[-61.62112,10.71765],[-61.62106,10.71755],[-61.62111,10.71755],[-61.62108,10.71751],[-61.62111,10.71754],[-61.62087,10.71742],[-61.62089,10.7173],[-61.62085,10.71711],[-61.62074,10.71697],[-61.6206,10.71689],[-61.62056,10.71674],[-61.6204,10.71672],[-61.6204,10.7162],[-61.62034,10.71595],[-61.62053,10.7157],[-61.62052,10.71551],[-61.62071,10.7151],[-61.62064,10.71488],[-61.62067,10.71451],[-61.62063,10.71437],[-61.62073,10.71416],[-61.62072,10.71406],[-61.6208,10.71394],[-61.62079,10.71396],[-61.62078,10.71391],[-61.62065,10.71387],[-61.62056,10.71368],[-61.62045,10.71363],[-61.62043,10.71342],[-61.62048,10.71338],[-61.6204,10.71336],[-61.62037,10.71331],[-61.62005,10.71324],[-61.61994,10.71325],[-61.61975,10.71311],[-61.61963,10.7131],[-61.61928,10.71295],[-61.61901,10.71294],[-61.61881,10.71288],[-61.61874,10.71291],[-61.61842,10.71292],[-61.61828,10.7129],[-61.61807,10.71282],[-61.61795,10.71274],[-61.61781,10.7128],[-61.6176,10.71275],[-61.61749,10.71281],[-61.61721,10.71285],[-61.61707,10.71294],[-61.6169,10.71295],[-61.61676,10.713],[-61.61674,10.71311],[-61.61642,10.71327],[-61.61609,10.71326],[-61.61591,10.71335],[-61.6159,10.7134],[-61.61576,10.71343],[-61.61559,10.71342],[-61.61523,10.71358],[-61.61521,10.71363],[-61.6147,10.71373],[-61.61457,10.7137],[-61.61413,10.71347],[-61.61393,10.7133],[-61.61372,10.71331],[-61.61364,10.71326],[-61.61337,10.71327],[-61.61307,10.71323],[-61.61243,10.71333],[-61.61226,10.71338],[-61.61193,10.71334],[-61.61168,10.71339],[-61.61148,10.71337],[-61.61124,10.71328],[-61.61083,10.71334],[-61.61055,10.71331],[-61.61044,10.71325],[-61.61026,10.71331],[-61.61011,10.71345],[-61.60982,10.71354],[-61.60958,10.71353],[-61.6095,10.7136],[-61.60922,10.71397],[-61.60895,10.7146],[-61.60897,10.71494],[-61.60905,10.71529],[-61.60913,10.71542],[-61.60912,10.71566],[-61.60921,10.71614],[-61.60945,10.71714],[-61.60957,10.71785],[-61.60976,10.71842]]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any ideas about this situation?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78072538/azure-maps-creator-unable-to-create-data-registry

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible issues:

- In your URL you are using the `pins` parameter rather than the `path` parameter and its style options.
- If that doesn't work, then make sure you are using the uuid from the mapData metadata service and not the data upload operation.

Here is the URL format I used:

> [https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=[key]&api-version=1.0&zoom=12&center=-61.60976,10.71847&path=lc0000FF|fc0000FF|lw3|la0.80|fa0.30||udid-01c5c14c-c9d3-f98b-1007-82f0b6d06304](https://atlas.microsoft.com/map/static/png?subscription-key=%5Bkey%5D&api-version=1.0&zoom=12&center=-61.60976,10.71847&path=lc0000FF%7Cfc0000FF%7Clw3%7Cla0.80%7Cfa0.30%7C%7Cudid-01c5c14c-c9d3-f98b-1007-82f0b6d06304)

Here is the map image it generated:

[image]