# Azure Maps Creator unable to create data registry

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I want to use 'Azure Maps Creator' to create a map, but according to the documentation, I am currently stuck in the step of how to create a data registry.

According to the request, I sent a request to create a data composition table, but it showed:

'**Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND us.atlas-microsoft.com**'

I don't know why, but I double checked the requirements in the document. The region selected by my Creator is indeed East US 2, but the sending still failed.

I tried many times, but couldn't solve it; And I couldn't find any related issues on the internet.

Request sent: https://us.atlas.microsoft.com/dataRegistries/ {udid}? API version=2023-06-01&subscription key={Your Azure Maps Subscription key}

Document address：[https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/azure-maps/how-to-create-data-registries?tabs=System-assigned#create-a-data-registry](https://stackoverflow.com)

us.atlas.microsoft.com:

[image: us.atlas.microsoft.com]

Region Is East US 2:

[image: Region Is East US 2]

Why does sending a request fail?

Comment: Based on timing and topic I suspect you may be the same person who posted this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1601566/azure-maps-creator-unable-to-create-data-registry in the Azure Maps forums. For others that come across this post: If you are physically in China, you won't be able to access the Azure Maps platform. The Azure Maps platform is currently not available from within China or South Korea at this time. If you use a VPN you may then be able to access the platform.

Comment: This is indeed my answer. I can access the Azure platform (VPN), but the problem I am facing is that I cannot successfully send a request to "us. atlas. microsoft.com", even if I have VPN enabled

Comment: Your request is sent to us.atlas.microsoft.com but the error message complains that us.atlas-microsoft.com cannot be found (note hyphen) shouldn these match?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it could be possible that the identity of the user is created outside US. The end point you are trying points to the `us.atlas.microsoft.com` geographical URL. If your account wasn't created in the United States, you must use a different geographical URL. Here are the geographical endpoints currently supported by creator service.

[image: User's image]

Please refer to the Prerequisites section of [How to create data registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-create-data-registries?tabs=System-assigned#prerequisites) for information on this.

Here is another article which provides information on [Creator service geographic scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/creator-geographic-scope#geographic-and-regional-mapping).

Hope this helps!

Comment: What you mean is that my Azure account needs to belong to the United States region, not my Creator (because I read the document that the API to be sent is determined based on the Creator)